# Android build warning Mapping new ns to old ns

Tags: android, build, build.gradle, warnings

I created a new project in android studio and added all the dependencies. All of them are latest. When I built the project I am getting these warnings. There is no code in the app. These started showing after I added the dependencies.

Should I just leave it like this?

[Sync output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MiQ8.png)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    def version_nav = "2.3.4"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.3.0"
    def version_retrofit_coroutines_adapter = "0.9.2"
    def version_kotlin_coroutines = "1.3.9"
    def version_moshi = "1.9.2"
    def retrofit ="2.9.0"
    def hilt_version = "2.31-alpha"
    def hilt_viewmodels = "1.0.0-alpha03"
    def fragment_ktx = "1.3.1"
    def okhttp = "4.9.0"
    def moshi_converter = "2.8.1"
    def recycler_view_version = "1.2.0-beta02"
    def timber_version = "4.7.1"
    def java_poet_version = "1.13.0"
    def coil_version = "1.1.1"


    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    // Timber
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timber_version"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit"

    // Moshi
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$version_moshi"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$version_moshi"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$moshi_converter"

    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$version_nav"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$version_nav"

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$version_kotlin_coroutines"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$version_kotlin_coroutines"

    // Retrofit Coroutines Support
    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:$version_retrofit_coroutines_adapter"

    //RecyclerView
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recycler_view_version"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycle only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    //OkHttp3
    implementation"com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp"

    //Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

    //Hilt View models
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$hilt_viewmodels"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hilt_viewmodels"

    //Fragments
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_ktx"

    //Java Poet
    kapt "com.squareup:javapoet:$java_poet_version"

    //Coil
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:$coil_version"

}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

The app is run without any issues but since this is a warning I have seen first time. I couldn't find anything related anywhere else, wanted to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same issue and turned out that the `buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"` used is not installed, so I switched to the installed `buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"` (in my case)  and the warning disappeared.

Comment: Dont use this buildToolsVersion at all.. If you still get the issue. Please invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: @NizamudeenSherif  not working this, `invalidate caches and restart`

Comment: please describe properly where is buldToolsVersion is mentioned

Answer (score 25):

This happens due to old gradle plugin version.

I did change the SDK version to 31 but my gradle plugin was 4.2. So I was facing this same issue.

To resolve this, Just go to your Project level build.gradle and update the gradle plugin version to the latest one like the following:

```
buildscript {

  // ...

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
  }
}
```

At the time of writing this answer, Gradle **7.0.2** is the latest version.

Comment: Also update your gradle-wrappers.properties with distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip

Comment: @RamkeshYadav In my case, the Android Studio did that automatically when I re-synced the project. Thanks for pointing it out. This is good point for those when the Studio doesn't do it automatically.

Answer (score 17):

I'm using  **Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1,Patch)** which point the `buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"` and got the same error.
I fixed it by just update the Android Gradle Plugin version from `4.1.0` to `7.0.2`.

[image: image reference]

Comment: In Android Studio you can also update the Gradle Plugin Version (and the Gradle Version) by going to File > Project Structure.

Comment: To open Upgrade assistant : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70971871/3139120

Comment: The upgrade assistant is what solved it for me. Thanks@fabienbranchel for linking how to open it.

Comment: Where do I find this assistent? If I go to Tools / AGP Upgrade Assistent, it does not show up.

Answer (score 16):

I've got a similar error message in **VSCode** building my **Flutter** app after upgrading Flutter to **version 3.0**. The following fixed it for me.

1. Update all Android SDK packages in Android Studio
2. In your "..\your_app\android\app\build.gradle" file change compileSdkVersion  to 31. If you also want to change your targetSdkVersion to 31, you have to add `android:exported="true"` or `android:exported="false"` in your "AndroidManifest.xml" file under `activity`. What you have to choose and more details on "android:exported" look here [android:exported details](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported)
3. In your "..\your_app\android\build.gradle" file change the "ext.kotlin_version" to `'1.6.10'` and "classpath" of your gradle version to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'`
4. In your "..\your_app\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties" file change the "distributionURL" to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip`
5. Do a `flutter clean` to delete the old build stuff.

After I have done that, build runs without any error or warning.

Edit: The original post was for Flutter version 2.10. I updated the versions number for Flutter version 3.0

Answer (score 4):

This helped me:

1. “Build -> Clean Project”
2. “File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart” choose “Invalidate and restart option” and close Android Studio

Comment: and if i'm working in flutter?

Answer (score 4):

1. In Android Studio you can also update the Gradle Plugin Version (and the Gradle Version) by going to File > Project Structure.
   [image]
2. Just go to your Project level build.gradle and update the gradle plugin version to the latest one like the following: `dependencies {classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'}`.
3. update gradle-wrapper.properties `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip`.

Comment: dependencies {classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'} A newer version of com.android.tools.build:gradle than 7.0.2 is available: 7.0.4 & distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip

Answer (score 1):

I installed Android Studio `Arctic Fox (2020.3.1)` and i started getting that same error on **vscode**!

> Mapping new ns to old ns blah blah

The ***FIX*** for me was to uninstall that version of android studio, install `4.2.2` from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) AND download SDK files then update it back to Arctic Fox [(from in UI)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkvK9.png) and issue was gone. I guess its a **SDK** bug ....

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: This answer is help me. In my case, i deleted Android 12 Preview (S) SDK - and install Android 10.0 (Q) - and this problem was solved )  The problem was in SDK...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, invalidating caches and restarting fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the "Java SDK" in the platform settings. Find it in project structure.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I try this  in **build.gradle(:app)** in `android`  and it make all thing OK:

```
  compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows**

Got to

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\build-tools

Now leave only one folder, I deleted all except 29.0.3

Restart your system and try again, the error should disappear

Answer (score 0):

I found a very easy solution of this while developing and Android app (flutter).

Step 1 - **Just come in Android SDK manager.**(by top right icon near search icon)
Step 2 - ***Uncheck higher level API. (in my case I unchecked API level above 29. if you want to know your max API selection , you can check with this folder name Path -
C:\Users\AarifHusain\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2
the last folder name 29.0.2 means I have to select SDK platform upto 29 and uncheck higher than 29)***

Step 3 - Now apply the changes and let Android studio do its work with network. This process took time depend upon your internet speed after that unzipping take time.
after this process if IDE show completion with something error. don't worry its will rectify after restart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issues while updating my older flutter project
older means updating from without null sefty to null sefty version

I added this fix and its working

ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

```
    dependencies {    
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Android build warning & Error 

1) Android Studio Dolphin 3.1 Patch

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
compileSdkVersion 33
android:exported="true"

Error :-
JDK 11 for that
com/android/tools/idea/gradle/run/OutputBuildAction has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
Error :-
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android

==>
Add this line :- 
Android Gradle Plugin Version :- 4.0.2
Gradler Wrapper :- 6.1.1
compileSdkVersion 30

Sdk location - Gradle Jdk  :-  11 version 11.0.17  / jvm 11

Clean and Rebuild it Run
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).