# Warning: Mapping new ns Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

When i run emulator i get this error. I've been struggling for an hour and couldn't figure it out. It started after the new update came.
Will it be fixed with the new update or is there a way to fix it? Also would ignoring this error and making an app cause problems?

And last one this part is changed. I used to be able to adjust the versions, now it gives an error when it changes. I mean min and target SDK versions.

```
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66722945/android-build-warning-mapping-new-ns-to-old-ns

Answer (score 1):

**1. Clean your project**

Run `flutter clean` command and make sure `<project>/build` folder and `<project>/android/build` is deleted.

**2. Update gradle.properties**

Got to `gradle-wrapper.properties` file located at `<project>/android/gradle` , then set value to `distributionUrl` to **whatever latest gradle distribution is available**, https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip

**3. Update project build.gradle**

Update your android `build.gradle` file located at `<project>/android/build.gradle` with new version of **Gradle** and **Kotlin** available at this time.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1' and ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

**4. Final Step**

Run `flutter packages get` command in terminal, then run your flutter app first it may take more time as IDE downloads new files.

**Hopefully It helped you**

Answer (score 0):

Check the build tools version in the Android module of the Flutter project. It's possible that the version being used doesn't match with build tools installed. What you can do here is bump the build tools version that you're using. To do this, you can navigate to the `android` build folder and open the project-level build.gradle, from there check the version configured and update.

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
  ...
}
```