# AGP Upgrade Assistant window not opening in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

When I press `Tools > AGP Upgrade Assistant` button, nothing happens.
[image: The button that I press]

I am using Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4. I also tried this on Bumblebee 2021.1.1 and the same problem occurs.

Other maybe relevant info

```
Fluter Android Studio plugin 63.2.1
Dart Android Studio plugin 203.8452
Dart 2.15.1
Flutter 2.8.1
Android gradle plugin 3.6.0
Gradle 6.1.1-all
```

Comment: Having exactly the same problem! did you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The AGP Upgrade Assistant opens only when you open the Android folder as an Android project

Comment: Yes, originally I was opening my project on the ../android folder. Once I opened the android folder as a project the AGP Upgrade Assistant opened :)

Comment: Just to add my voice to the choir: This is what worked for me. And the upgrade assistant then updgraded Gradle and its dependencies -which is what I needed.

Comment: I have the same problem now with Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1. The described solution does not work for me. Anybody else with the same problem?

Comment: @Harry, I experience the same with  2022.2.1 Patch 1

Comment: Is there a reason for this roundabout behavior? This still doesn't work for me and I open my project by going to File > Open > MyProject.

Comment: There is a new option under Tools > Flutter > Open for editing in Android Studio. After a lot of syncing and indexing you can run the APG upgrade assistant from the Tools menu. I could upgrade to 7.4.1, but a subsequent upgrade to 8.0.1 failed.....

Comment: Verified, Fails on this | Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1

Comment: Useless answer. You should show how to open the Android Folder as an Android Project.

Comment: You really have to go through File > Open  and open the Android directory under your flutter project. Wait until the Android Studio is ready with all kind of analysis and update stuff. Then go to Tools > AGP update assistant

Answer (score 3):

As HWK's answer you should open Tools---> Flutter ---> Open Android module in Android Studio

[image]

It will open another window which opens the Android folder as in the below image.

[image]

Comment: Nope, that does not work. you really have to go through File > Open  and open de Android directory under your flutter project. Wait until the Android Sudio is ready with all kind of analysis and update stuf. Then go to Tools > AGP update assistant