# Android Gradle Plugin Upgrade Assistant does not open in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've never user AGP before.

I need to configure gradle and gradle plugin versions, but when i click on Tool -> AGP upgrade assistance, it does nothing.

I have tried this on a normal Android Studio installation, then full uninstall (all related files too) and installed through JetBrains toolbox (since i use all their other IDEs too).
Still doesnt open.

Does it (AGP assistant) need to be installed somehow or something of that sort? Im clueless.

Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70971871/12774969

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AGP Upgrade Assistant window not opening in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70880154/agp-upgrade-assistant-window-not-opening-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new generated `build.gradle` file like mine, you can go to the app `build.gradle.kts`. You can see the plugin block:

```
plugins {
  alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
  ...
}
```

Hit `Ctrl/Cmd + click` on the application it will take you to `libs.versions.toml`. From there you can modify the version of agp